# How to persist entity object retrieved from a JTable through JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, jtable

I have been trying for days to persists data obtained from a jtable from an imported Excel sheet without success and trying to find the exception is sickening.

here is some part of the code and the error stack trace

```
@Action
public void persist(){
emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MauranaSurveyPU");
em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();

//loops through table to retrieve object and persist

int count = jTable1.getRowCount();
for(int i=0; i<count; i++){

Mauranagroup mn = new Mauranagroup(); 
String obj1 = (String)GetData(jTable1,i,0);
String obj2 = (String)GetData(jTable1,i,1);
String obj3 = (String)GetData(jTable1,i,2);

//set entity
mn.setRespondentId(Integer.parseInt(obj1));        
mn.setMale(obj2);         
mn.setFemale(obj3);  

em.persist(mn);   
}//end for

em.getTransaction().commit();        



}//end method persist


// get object from jtable
private Object GetData(JTable jTable1, int x, int y) {
return jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(x,y);
}
```

The problem with this code is that it actually persists ,but after the transaction commits 
i get this stack trace;

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL130204062549290' defined on 'MAURANAGROUP'.
>   Error Code: 20000
>   Call: INSERT INTO MAURANAGROUP (RESPONDENT_ID, AMOUNTTOBESPENT, AREYOUFAMILIARNO
>
> bind => [211 parameters bound]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(entity.Mauranagroup[ respondentId=5 ])

**when i delete the records and persist again, i get another line**

> bind => [211 parameters bound]
>   Query: InsertObjectQuery(entity.Mauranagroup[ respondentId=2 ])
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)

i dont understand is it,it actually persist and i can see my saved data. is it the loop or is the loop not terminating well,im actually sick because of this project.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DB constraint on your table that some column is unique and you are inserting the duplicate value. I guess it is the `RESPONDENT_ID`. If you are trying to persist all the record in the table for the first time, I wouldn't provide the id from the table data. Instead I would use sequence to generate the id for you and return it to the UI.

If you are trying to modify the existing data stored in the table. I would search them in the DB using the id, update the fields and persist them again.

btw. it is a good practice to name your methods with lowercase at the beginning.

Comment: I tried using the generatedValue but didn't know how to use it,it kept saying respondentId cannot accept null value,I actually change the anotation to @GeneratedValue and the strategy to auto,didn't seem to be working,I also tried using a Random object,it worked sortof but seemed to have affected my query result